# Why isn't this .change event firing in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, onchange

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>System Toolbox</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $document.ready(function() {

            $("#SearchFor").change(function() {
                    alert($(this).val());
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Search for: <select name="SearchFor" id="SearchFor">
            <option value="company">Company</option>
            <option value="user">User</option>
            <option value="bundle">Bundle</option>
            <option value="course">Course</option>
        </select>
        <div id="SearchType"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No javascript errors per firebug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your document.ready statement is incorrect. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    ...

});
```

Comment: While the other two answers are correct, this one actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
$document.ready(function() {
```

But should be this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(function() { //Shortcut for $(document).ready();
   $("#SearchFor").change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Also, best to use script tags like this still:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See this question for more detail: [Why don’t self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: Crockford advises against providing the "type" attribute at all.

Comment: @Pointy - Who?  It's a required attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

Comment: @Pointy - While that's mostly good advice, I wouldn't leave out the type attribute.  Simple rule for me: Having it won't cause any issues, *not* having it can (and **will** in older browsers).

Comment: The reason it's problematic is that you've got to worry about what your server is going to return. In other words, the attribute on the tag second-guesses the MIME type that'll be returned in the HTTP request to actually fetch the script. In my opinion the attribute on the tag was simply a design mistake.

Comment: Also, since Netscape 2 the default interpretation of script content has been Javascript, so there's no realistic concern with "older browsers". If you find a browser where the default type isn't Javascript or where the lack of the attribute fails, I suspect that a vast number of other things would be likely to fail too.

Comment: @Pointy - I can't put it better than this: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/09/17/should-i-use-a-type-attribute-on-script-tags.aspx pay attention to the comments for a lot of great points.

Comment: Well the conclusion in that article is "be standards-compliant, oh except don't".  The attribute is required, but the standards-compliant values don't work.  Again, the whole thing seems like a mistake, so slavish standards-compliance seems pointless to me. *Chacun à son goût.*

Answer (score 0):

should just be

```
$(function() {
  $("#SearchFor").change(function() {
                alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$document` is not a valid reference to a jQuery object, try

```
$(document)
```

Notice the parenthesis